# Extracting string between words using logical operators in rm_between function

Tags: r, string, qdapregex

I am trying to extract strings between words. Consider this example -

```
x <-  "There are 2.3 million species in the world"
```

This may also take another form which is

```
x <-  "There are 2.3 billion species in the world"
```

I need the text between `There` and either '`million` or `billion`, including them. The presence of million or billion is decided on run time, it is not decided before hand. So the output which I need from this sentence is

`[1] There are 2.3 million` OR
`[2] There are 2.3 billion`

I am using `rm_between` function from `qdapRegex` package for the same. Using this command I can extract only one of them at a time.

```
library(qdapRegex)
rm_between(x, 'There', 'million', extract=TRUE, include.markers = TRUE)
```

OR I have to use

```
rm_between(x, 'There', 'billion', extract=TRUE, include.markers = TRUE)
```

How can I write a command which can check presence of `million` or `billion` in the same sentence. Something like this -

```
rm_between(x, 'There', 'billion' || 'million', extract=TRUE, include.markers = TRUE)
```

I hope this is clear. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Dear XYZ, explanation for the down vote please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `left` and `right` arguments in `rm_between` takes a `vector` of character/numeric symbols.  So you can use a vector with equal length in both `left/right` arguments.

```
 library(qdapRegex)
 unlist(rm_between(x, rep('There',2), c('million', 'billion'),
                         extract=TRUE, include.markers=TRUE))
 #[1] "There are 2.3 million" "There are 2.3 billion"
 unlist(rm_between(x1, rep('There',2), c('million', 'billion'),
                         extract=TRUE, include.markers=TRUE))
 #[1] "There are 2.3 million"

 unlist(rm_between(x2, rep('There',2), c('million', 'billion'),
                         extract=TRUE, include.markers=TRUE))
 #[1] "There are 2.3 billion"
```

Or

```
  sub('\\s*species.*', '', x)
```

#### data

```
 x <-  c("There are 2.3 million species in the world", 
   "There are 2.3 billion species in the world")
 x1 <- "There are 2.3 million species in the world"
 x2 <- "There are 2.3 billion species in the world"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @akrun . However, the data which you have provided is not accurate. At any given time, only one of the sentence can be true. So either its "There are 2.3 million species in the world" OR its "There are 2.3 billion species in the world".

Comment: @RonakShah Please check my updates.  It works for individual cases also.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `str_extact_all` (for global matching) or `str_extract` (single match)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(s, "\\bThere\\b.*?\\b(?:million|billion)\\b")
```

or

```
str_extract_all(s, perl("(?<!\\S)There(?=\\s+).*?\\s(?:million|billion)(?!\\S)"))
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>With [`rm_between`](http://trinker.github.io/qdapRegex_dev/rm_between.html) you can supply a vector for multiple markers of equal length as the doc states.</strike>

### EDIT

See @TylerRinker's [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31628815/2206004) for the updated arguments for `rm_between`.

Although, another method that you can use a user defined regex would be [`rm_default`](http://trinker.github.io/qdapRegex_dev/rm_default.html) :

```
rm_default(x, pattern='There.*?[bm]illion', extract=TRUE)
```

**Example**:

```
library(qdapRegex)

x <-  c(
    'There are 2.3 million species in the world',
    'There are 2.3 billion species in the world'
)

rm_default(x, pattern = 'There.*?[bm]illion', extract = TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "There are 2.3 million"

## [[2]]
## [1] "There are 2.3 billion"
```

Answer (score 2):

@hwnd's (my fellow **qdapRegex** co-author) response inspired a discussion that has lead to a new argument, `fixed`, for `rm_between`.  The following description is in the dev version:

> `rm_between` and `r_between_multiple` pick up a `fixed` argument.  Previously, `left` and `right` boundaries containing regular expression special characters   were fixed by default (escaped).  This did not allow for the powerful use of a regular expression for left/right boundaries.  The `fixed = TRUE` behavior is still the default but users can now set `fixed = FALSE` to work with regular expression boundaries.  This new feature was inspired by @Ronak Shah's StackOverflow question: [Extracting string between words using logical operators in rm_between function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31623069/1000343)

To install the dev version:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_install_gh("trinker/qdapRegex")
```

Using **qdapRegex** version >= 4.1 you can do the following.

```
x <-  c(
    "There are 2.3 million species in the world",
    "There are 2.3 billion species in the world"
)

rm_between(x, left='There', right = '[mb]illion', fixed = FALSE,
    include=TRUE, extract = TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "There are 2.3 million"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "There are 2.3 billion"
```